# What literary device am I thinking of?

Tags: literary-device

It's a fancy word used primarily in literary analysis to describe when the author allows the reader to predict a future event by dropping hints. This may not be the best example, but when a storm implies that something bad is going to happen. Can someone help? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Do you mean [foreshadowing](http://literarydevices.net/foreshadowing/)?

Answer (score 1):

Foreshadow, presage, portend, etc.